# How to check on nodes' content in Text.XML.Cursor?

Tags: haskell, xml-conduit

I have this XPath works with xmllint

```
//td[text() = 'USD']/../td[6]/text()
```

Now I want it to be done in Haskell. But following (not complete of the original XPath) does not work at all. I got empty list error on head.

```
cur $// element "td" &// check (\c → "USD" ≡ head (c $// content))
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `head` with `mconcat` to get _all_ of the descendant text nodes instead of just the first one? You may also need to consider using `strip` to get rid of whitespace.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Ah, I see. Thanks.